# Validating if string contains date

Tags: javascript, string, html, date

Im currently facing a problem:

I have .txt file which im going through.. I want to validate if a line of text contains date (format: yyyy/mm/dd).

Line example: **2015/01/05 12 John's mother.**

Regex im using: `var dateType = /^(\d{4})([\/-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})$/;`

What would be the best way to reach this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the only real problem with your regex not working is that you are trying to match start `^` and end `$`. So remove those for a 'contains' logic:

```
/(\d{4})([\/-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})/
```

You can then use this regex in your javascript with the `test()` function as follows:

```
var dateType = /(\d{4})([\/-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})/;
var isMatch = dateType.test(myLine[i]);

if(isMatch){
    //...
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zjn8a7vp/)

---

However, if you know it will always *start* with a date, then keep the `^`. That way you are less likely to get unexpected matches if for example you don't want lines that end with a date.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Tho, problem is that I can't find a way to validate if string contains 'date type'... Im using if sentence.. `if(myLine[i] 'Problem im facing'){
    console.log(myLine[i]);
}`

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm!